# XSLT node equality matching everything

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, transformation

I have an XML file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<list>
    <report file="onefile.xml" oneAttr="2123as"></report>
    <report file="myfile.xml" oneAttr="blabla"></report>
    <report file="myfile.xml" oneAttr="2123as"></report>
    <report file="another.xml" oneAttr="2123as"></report>
</list>     <!-- changed by edit -->
```

And I need a stylesheet that can add a new report element after the last match of `@file="myfile.xml"`.

What I have got so far:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/list">
    <list>
    <xsl:variable name="insertAfter" select="report[@file='myfile.xml'][last()]"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="report">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="current() = $insertAfter">
            <report file="newFile.xml"></report>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </list>
</xsl:template>
```

The XSLT above is not working, the equality comparison seems not to work as expected and is matching all the reports, and consequently adding the new node element every time. I assume that perhaps it is not checking the equality on the attributes, and only on the text inside which is empty.

I know in XSLT 2.0 there is this "eq" operator which perhaps is doing what I intend, but I would like to stick to XSLT 1.0.

Any suggestions for a solution?

Comment: Just to be clear, comparing two nodes using the "=" operator compares their string values, and the string value of all your report elements is a zero-length string, so they are all equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your verbal description 'last match of @file="myfile.xml"' translates into

```
<xsl:template match="report[@file = 'myfile.xml'][last()]">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  <report file="newFile.xml"></report>
</xsl:template>
```

so all you seem to need is

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="report[@file = 'myfile.xml'][last()]">
      <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
      <report file="newFile.xml"></report>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiJU

Node identity checking in XSLT 2 exists but would be done with the `is` operator, not with `eq`. But you don't need it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using the [`generate-id(...)` function](https://www.w3.org/2005/04/xpath-functions/#xslt-summary) to create an unique ID of the `last()` node and match it:

```
<xsl:template match="/list">
    <list>
    <xsl:variable name="insertAfter" select="generate-id(report[@file='myfile.xml'][last()])"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="report">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="generate-id(current()) = $insertAfter">
            <report file="newFile.xml"></report>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </list>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<list>
    <report file="onefile.xml" oneAttr="2123as"/>    
    <report file="myfile.xml" oneAttr="blabla"/>    
    <report file="myfile.xml" oneAttr="2123as"/>
    <report file="newFile.xml"/>
    <report file="another.xml" oneAttr="2123as"/>    
</list>
```